# Sharepoint Framework

Tags: nodejs, npm, sharepoint-online, paquetes-npm

Hola a todos estoy intentando realizar un widget para mi sitio `SharePoint`, realizando un mini proyecto React.

El problema que tengo es que intento conectarlo con el comando `gulp serve`, pero no se conecta con `SharePoint`.

Y aparece el siguiente error.

```
openssl config failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
```